# Does GDPR disclosure apply to European citizen temporarily in United States?

Tags: gdpr, multiple-jurisdiction

For some background: the EU "[Data Protection Directive][1]" is a European Union directive which regulates the processing of personal data within the European Union, as explained in [this Wikipedia article][2]. Among these regulations is the rule that individuals have right for a copy of the data that has been collected about them.

The question is, what about cases such as an EU citizen who is in United States on, say, a temporary 2-year work assignment sent by their employer? Let's say that during his stay in USA he becomes a member of an international organization that stores some details about him, or creates an account at some website that gathers information about his online behavior.

Questions:

1. Would data collected by the EU citizen in this case also be subject
   to the GDPR disclosure laws?
2. Would the EU citizen have to return to EU in order to be able to
   request a copy of his data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No

GDPR applies to people (not just citizens) who are in the EU. It has no applicability if both parties are not in the EU.

Comment: In EU, not in Europe. Geographically, Belarus is Europe too.

Comment: Also at least some French and Dutch territories in North America/South America/Caribbean would be part of the EU jurisdiction. But that was implicitly already included in this answer. Thank you for the answer, @Dale M.